# Declare empty numpy.ndarray and fill it

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array 'x' and a hop size 'N', I have to create a function that will return a numpy.ndarray with the values of 'x' that fit the hop size, for example, if x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and N = 2, the function would return output = [0,2,4,6,8]. So far I have thought of the following:

```
def hopSamples(x,N)
    i = 0
    n = len(x)
    output = numpy.ndarray([])
    while i<n:
        output.append(x[i])
        i = i+N
    return output
```

but it gives errors. How can I manage this? I am just starting python so I am sure there will be plenty of errors, so any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Posting the exact errors you're getting would be useful in the future, although the answers you got are excellent.

Comment: Also, your question title doesn't really fit your question description. The way to "declare (actually, create) an empty array and fill it" is `np.zeros` plus normal index-setting. But what you want to do doesn't require that in the first place.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I see it now. I apologize for my lack of knowledge in Python, I began using it just last week. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slicing:

```
In [14]: arr = np.arange(0, 10)

In [15]: arr
Out[15]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [16]: arr[::2]
Out[16]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Thus, your function would simply look like this:

```
def hopSamples1(x, N):
    return x[::N]
```

---

If you're insistent on declaring an empty array beforehand and filling it using a loop, you can alter your function a bit to do one of the following.

- You can initializes an empty array and extend it by another cell with each iteration of the loop. Note that a new array is created and returned each time.

  ```
  def hopSamples2(x, N):
      i = 0
      n = len(x)
      output = np.empty(shape = 0, dtype = x.dtype)
      while i < n:
          output = np.append(output, x[i])
          i += N
      return output
  ```
- An alternative implementation would be creating the entire array beforehand, but setting the values into its cells one by one.

  ```
  def hopSamples3(x, N):
      i = 0
      n = len(x)
      m = n / N
      output = np.ndarray(shape = m, dtype = x.dtype)
      while i < m:
          output[i] = x[i * N]
          i += 1
      return output
  ```

A simple benchmark test shows that using slicing is the quickest approach while extending the array one by one is the slowest:

```
In [146]: %time hopSamples1(arr, 2)
CPU times: user 21 µs, sys: 3 µs, total: 24 µs
Wall time: 28.8 µs
Out[146]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])

In [147]: %time hopSamples2(arr, 2)
CPU times: user 241 µs, sys: 29 µs, total: 270 µs
Wall time: 230 µs
Out[147]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])

In [148]: %time hopSamples3(arr, 2)
CPU times: user 35 µs, sys: 5 µs, total: 40 µs
Wall time: 45.8 µs
Out[148]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! In fact I could do it either way, but my previous knowledge of Matlab made me think that the one I explained was a good way to do it, but then you guys showed me the easiest way, which I didn't know, and that's how I did it. So, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
print "Please input a step number: "
N = int(raw_input())
b = a[::N]
print "b is: ", b
```

Answer (score 1):

use numpy slicing, basically, [start:stop:step](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing):

```
In [20]: xs
Out[20]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [21]: xs[::2]
Out[21]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```